# Date format in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

how to change the date time format 2011-09-01 09:39:23 to 2011-Aug-01 09:39:23 in asp.net.

And While displaying it should display the second format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use one of the [DateTime Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) with `DateTime.ToString()`

In particular, you will want:

```
yourDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: THIS only if his server or web.config is setted to USA Culture (and perhaps other cultures around the world that use `Aug` as the August month abbreviation, the `-` as a date separator, the `:` as the time separator and use "our" years)